# Fetch Only User Objects Firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my Firebase database I have a list of nodes that users can create. For example:

```
car: {
     $uid: {
          data...
     }
}
```

All users can create a `car`. However, users should on;y be allowed to fetch their `car` nodes that they made.

I've tried a few mixes of security rules and queries, storing the users `uid` in each `car` so I know which user made it. However I haven't had any luck.

How can I achieve this? The combo of security rules and queries is throwing my brain off a little!

Comment: you shoud create main parent node is a user id and add car as a child of userid's node so you can get the data by user id

Comment: Firebase recommend to keep the database as flat as possible and I agree. Storing individual `car` nodes under relevant `user` nodes seems to go against this. Unless I misunderstand?

Comment: nope that wont go again ruls and if you store data based on login user then what it against ruls ?

Comment: Ahh, I was misunderstanding you initially. I get it now. I don't store the users `car` nodes under the actual `user` node, but have each user again and their `car`s under the `car` node. E.g See example under 'Using Indices...' title here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "cars": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With these rules a signed-in user can create whatever they want under their own `cars` subnode. If you only want them to create/update/delete a single car at a time, you'd:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "cars": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        "$carid": {
          ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In these rules, the user can still *read* their entire list of cars. But they can only create/update/delete the cars one at a time.